# How can I print a 9x9 table in just one line?

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to print a 9x9 multiplication table in just one line of code. I am having trouble with below result.

```
print("%s x %s = %s" % (x, y, x*y) for x in range(1, 10) for y in range(1, 10))
```

Outputs:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1054350f0>
```

While I'd expected it to output:

```
1 x 1 = 1
1 x 2 = 2
.
.
.
9 x 9 = 81
```

Comment: Please print with using generator or lambda in python. Thanks.

Comment: You were 13 characters away: `print(*("%s x %s = %s" % (x, y, x*y) for x in range(1, 10) for y in range(1, 10)), sep='\n')`.  (Note: this works in python2 if you add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the module).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
>>> table = ("%s x %s = %s" % (x, y, x*y) for x in range(1, 10) for y in range(1, 10))
>>> print "\n".join(table)
1 x 1 = 1
1 x 2 = 2
.
.
.
9 x 9 = 81
```

Or in one line:

```
print "\n".join(("%s x %s = %s" % (x, y, x*y) for x in range(1, 10) for y in range(1, 10)))
```